# Subset Array by another Array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, subset

I'm new to javascript and have a simple task.  I have an array "values" and a second array "gender", and I want to create a third array which is "values" where gender == "Males".  The variables look like this:

```
var values = new Array();
values[0] = .1
values[1] = .3
values [2] = .7
values[3] = .8
var gender = new Array();
gender[0]='Males'
gender[1]='Males'
gender[2]='Females'
gender[3]='Females'
```

The equivalent syntax in python would be:

```
female_values = values[gender=='Females']
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't know what Python you program in, but in my version the syntax for what you want would be something like `female_values = [values[i] for i, sex in enumerate(gender) if sex == 'Females']`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var values = [.1, .3, .7, .8];
var gender = ['Males', 'Males', 'Females', 'Females'];

var males = [];
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
  if (gender[i] == 'Males') {
    males.push(values[i]);
  }
}
```

The `Array` constructor is not usually used, use the array literal `[]` instead.  Then simply loop through the arrays and push the value onto the third array if some condition that you set passes.

---

And yeah this is more pain than python, although [coffee script can make it a little nicer](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/#try%3avalues%20=%20%5B.1,%20.3,%20.7,%20.8%5D%0Agender%20=%20%5B%27Males%27,%20%27Males%27,%20%27Females%27,%20%27Females%27%5D%0Amales%20=%20%28values%5Bi%5D%20for%20i%20in%20%5B0...values.length%5D%20when%20gender%5Bi%5D%20==%20%27Males%27%29).

Comment: Great, thanks for the answer and general feedback (I'm just getting started).

Comment: Not that it matters much in small arrays, but you should cache the length of the array in a temporary variable so that it doesn't have to be calculated for every iteration.

Comment: Quick related question -- if I only want to identify a single value, is there a way to do it without looping?  Thanks.

Comment: Javscript has almost no native support for any kind of snazzy iteration.  So anytime you want an item/items from an array and you don't know the index aleady, then you have to loop.  No way around it.

Answer (score 0):

nicer way

```
var values = [.1, .3, .7, .8],
    gender = ['Males', 'Males', 'Females', 'Females'],
    males  = [],
    i      = values.length;

while ( i-- ) {
    gender[i] == 'Males' && males.unshift(values[i])
}
```

Comment: Adjectives like `nice` can be quite subjective.  You version is probably ever so slightly faster, but its less readable because it relies on a bit more magic especially for a javascript beginner.  Also the items in the resulting array will be reversed with this approach.

Comment: yes, sorry, result is reversed there. Replaced the push with unshift. Should be fine now.